# Appending to a line in a CSV file

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

Let's say I have a CSV file like this after running the following code:

```
Andy, 4 
Bochr, 2
John, 9

import csv

name = input('name: ')
score = input('score: ')

with open('test.csv', 'a') as f:
    a = csv.writer(f)
    data = [name, score]
    a.writerow(data)
```

If I was to run that code again and my name is Andy, how would I append my score to the first line instead of starting a new row with the name Andy? 
For example, let's say I scored 5 again. How would you append it to the first line Andy to look like:

```
Andy, 4, 5 
Bochr, 2
John, 9
```

Thank you in advance,

Comment: you would have to read all your lines into some sort of data structure (probably a dict or a list) then change the values in those lists before writing everything back to the file with `w` mode to overwrite everything

Comment: @RNar How would you do that?

Comment: 'append' means 'add to the end' of the file. You want to insert text into the middle of the file, and there is no mechanism provided to do that, so the simplest way is to re-write the whole file. It sounds like you are trying to use a CSV file as if it was an updatable database, which it is not. Issues such as this are the reason why real databases are a good idea.

Comment: Which part exactly is causing issues? That said, CSV files are not different than other files, it is not possible to insert data in the middle.

Comment: basic usage of [inputting and outputting](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files). I suggest reading each file as a dict of lists like `data = {line[0]:line[1:] for each line.split() in f}` where `f` is your file, opened with `'r'` mode

Comment: What about just inserting text at the end of Andy, so it will produce: `Andy, 4, 5`

Comment: There is no way to 'insert text' into the middle of a file. You have to manually read the rest of the file, write your text in the correct location, and then rewrite the rest of the file. Very messy. Much better in most cases to just rewrite the whole file.

Comment: @Galax How would you rewrite the whole file to add it to its particular position?

Comment: You'd have to search through the existing disk file to find the right place to insert the text. It would be horrible- slow, error prone, and difficult to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want something that acts more like a database or data-structure than a text file.  One solution with a very readable data format is json:

```
import json
initial_data = {
    'Andy': [4],
    'Bochr': [2],
    'John': [9],
}
with open('test.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(initial_data, fp, indent=4)
```

then your update would be much simpler:

```
with open('test.json', 'r') as fp:
    data = json.load(fp)
data['Andy'].append(5)
```

and saving the updated data:

```
with open('test.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(initial_data, fp, indent=4)
```

Comment: Thank you! I initially considered using a JSON file but I didn't know how to add create the intitial_data dictionary in the first place using the variable name and score? I didn't know how to set name to a new key and then assign the score as the value. Could you shed some light on that?

Comment: @Aweys not sure what you mean..?  The first code-block in the answer creates the initial data file.  Run it and look at the content of the `test.json` file...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import csv

name = input('name: ')
score = input('score: ')
rows_list = []
with open('test.csv') as fin:
    reader = csv.reader(fin)
    for row in reader:
      if row[0] == name:
         row[1] = score
      rows_list.append(row)  
with open('test.csv', 'w') as f:
    a = csv.writer(f)
    data = rows_list
    a.writerows(data)
```

Remember, this assumes you already have a test.csv present

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've run it and it comes back with this error:  `for row in reader:
io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable`

Comment: Also, using that code, if name is not andy, how would you just append it normally to the text.csv file?

Comment: Updated the answer. Have a look.